# Multiple SQL transactions on a network server

Tags: sql-server, networking, transactions

I am developing an application that will be used by many users in the same time (on a network). The application will use SQL Server.

I want to know if it's good to use transactions for different queries that I have. If one user start a transaction at a time and another user starts one more, will the server know whom is a random transaction? Multiple transactions at a time are supported by one single server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, SQLServer supports multiple simultaneous transactions. There would be no point in having transactions if you could not run more than one at a time.

Comment: does a transaction have an id? how a c# application can distinguish which is its transaction? does the server verify whom started the transaction ?

Comment: An application must keep track of its transactions by keeping a handle to them as long as they are active. How this is done depends on the programming environment, but you usually keep some kind of session object around for that. The server also maintains each transaction's state, and knows which session they belong to. You seem to think a transaction started by one session could be "intercepted" or manipulated in some way by another session. That is not the case.